# Complex filtering R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of three variables: number of sick days, age and gender.

```
       Sick days     Age  Gender
    1           5      39   F
    2           4      54   М
    3           5      42   М
    4           4      38   М
   ...
```

The aim is to plot a bar chart, in order to prove that the number of people older 35y miss more than 2 working days in a year more often than people under the age 35.

I easily did this filtration using traditional methods:

```
> data2<- subset(data, Sick.days>2) 
> sum(data2$Age > 35)
  [1] 115
> sum(data2$Age <= 35)
  [1] 36
```

But I wanted to use **dplyr** to get more elegant solution and I've been stuck. I don't understand how to calculate the number of filtered rows without using summarize.

This is the example of how I did another filtration by Gender. I'd like to get something similar.

```
data%>% filter(Sick.days > 2) %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarize(number=n()) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x=Gender,y=number)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(group=Genser),stat="identity", width= 0.4, alpha=0.6,color="blue") + 
  labs(x="Gender",y="number of cases") + coord_flip()+theme_bw()
```

Do you have any suggestions how to solve the problem using **dplyr**?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using summarise? It is a crucial method of the dplyr library.

Comment: Because normally Summarise is used after group_by. After Filter it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(sick_days = c(5,4,5,4,4,1),
                age = c(39,54,42,38,25,36),
                gender = c("F","M","M","M","F", "M"))

df = df %>%
  filter(sick_days > 2) %>%
  mutate(age_grp = ifelse(age > 35, ">35", "<=35"))

plot = ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=age_grp))

print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: I like your approach! But the number of days shouldn't be divided, I suppose it is one column for people older 35yo and one column for people younger 35.

Comment: Okay, so you want one bar for the count of under 35s with more than 2 sick days and one bar for the counts of over 35s with more than 2 sick days. I edited my comment with code to do that.

Comment: Looks beautiful now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to approach this with a set of Null <35. All the observations in the Age Variable column are >35. I would think about using a two-table verb Set operation. Set operations, which combine the observations in the data sets as if they were set elements. Where table1 == <35 table2 == >35. Hope this helps.
Paul

Comment: Sorry, I didn't indicate that dataset contains 217 rows. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

But the `summarise` approach would be more efficient, just generate a new `age_group` variable within the `pipe`. I used that data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("Sick_days     Age      Gender
  5           39        F
  4           54        М
  5           42        М
  4           38        М
  4           23        F")
```

The code:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(age_group=case_when(Age >=35 ~ ">=35",
                              Age <35 ~ "<35")) %>%    # here you define a new variable
   filter(Sick_days>=2) %>%
   group_by(age_group) %>%
   summarise(sum_sick=sum(Sick_days)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   ggplot(aes(age_group, sum_sick)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   theme_bw()
```

Output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a methodology perspective you may want to consider reporting the data on sick days <2 before you filter it.  Since I just finished submitting to CRAN you may also want to look at the little PlotXTabs function I wrote which will give you your plot with mice labelling etc.  So...

```
require(dplyr)
require(CGPfunctions)
df <- data.frame(sick_days = c(5,4,5,4,4,1),
               age = c(39,54,42,38,25,36),
               gender = c("F","M","M","M","F", "M"))

df <- df %>%
         mutate(age_grp = ifelse(age > 35, ">35", "<=35"),
                sick_grp = ifelse(sick_days > 2, ">2", "<=2"))

PlotXTabs(df,sick_grp,age_grp)
PlotXTabs(df,sick_grp,age_grp,"percent")
PlotXTabs(df,sick_grp,age_grp,"stack")
```

[image: first example only]